# Absolute positioning does not work even if the parent is set to relative

Tags: css

```
<header>
    <div class="row header-top">
        <div class="row-inner">
            <a href="/test1/" class="testxyz">
                <i class="icon icon-test"></i>
                <i icon-color="" class="icon icon-test" ng-style="{color: color}" style="color: rgb(51, 191, 238);"></i>
            </a>            
            <div class="header-here">
                <span>here</span>
                <ul class="header-here-list">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span ng-controller="CNController" class="ng-scope">
        <div class="row header-nav">
            <div class="row-inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</header>
```

I'm trying to position div with class `lb-ad-test` the same as the div with class `row header-top`. I tried adding `position: relative` to the div with class `row header-top` and then added `position: absolute` to the div with class `lb-ad-test` and set `top` & `right` to `0`, but the content in div does not show up when I do that. How can I place the content in the 
below div same as the div with class `row header-top`?

```
<div ng-view="" class="app-container ng-scope">
  <div id="lb-test" class="lb-ad-test ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" >
  </div>     
</div>

CSS: 
.header-top {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  height: 93px;
  position: relative;
}

.lb-ad-test {
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: If you clean up your example you'll find the error your self... :)

Answer (score 0):

Change .leaderboard-ad-homepage in the CSS to .lb-ad-test? Your class names currently don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to  set one class with `left=0` and `top = 0`.

Comment: please elaborate as to how this answers the question. recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer